# Оптимизация кода js (создание нескольких элементов)

Tags: javascript

Нужно создать большой `div`, в котором будет еще несколько элементов, все это должно выглядеть так

При помощи `innerHTML` это сделать не получается, потому что работа с бд, и новый элемент не создается.

Я делаю так, но код слишком громоздкий и хотелось бы уменьшить его по возможности

```js
const div = document.createElement("div");
div.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);

const divinfo = document.createElement("div");
divinfo.className = "info_pack";

const divrow = document.createElement("div");
divrow.className = "info_pack_row";

const divrowimg = document.createElement("div");
divrowimg.className = "info_pack_row_img";

const img = document.createElement("img");
img.style.width = "30px";
img.style.height = "30px";
img.src = doc.data().src;

const divrowtxt = document.createElement("div");
divrowtxt.className = "info_pack_text";
divrowtxt.textContent = doc.data().cryptoname;

const divpackmoney = document.createElement("div");
divpackmoney.className = "info_pack_money";
divpackmoney.textContent = doc.data().income;


const span = document.createElement('span');
span.textContent = "$";
divpackmoney.appendChild(span);


divrowimg.appendChild(img);
divrow.appendChild(divrowimg);
divrow.appendChild(divrowtxt);
divinfo.appendChild(divrow);
divinfo.appendChild(divpackmoney);
div.appendChild(divinfo);
orders.appendChild(div);
```

```html
<div class="info_pack">
  <div class="info_pack_row">
    <div class="info_pack_row_img">
      <img src="images/XRP.png" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;">
    </div>
    <div class="info_pack_text">ripple</div>
  </div>
  <div class="info_pack_money">1008.00<span>$</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: посмотрите на jquery или d3.js, с ними полегче генертить огромные простыни

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Подумайте об использовании js-шаблонизатора. Например, handlebars

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать `innerHTML` - это немного сократит код.

```js
add.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const info = createInfoPack({
    text: 'ripple',
    summa: {
      value: '1008.00',
      currency: '$'
    }
  })
  document.querySelector('.info').appendChild(info);
});

function createInfoPack(data) {
  const info = document.createElement('div');
  info.innerHTML = `<div class="info_pack">
  <div class="info_pack_row">
    <div class="info_pack_row_img">
      <img src="images/XRP.png" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;">
    </div>
    <div class="info_pack_text"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="info_pack_money"><span class="currency-value"></span><span class="currency"></span></div>
</div>`;
  info.querySelector('.info_pack_text').textContent = data.text;
  info.querySelector('.info_pack_money .currency-value').textContent = data.summa.value;
  info.querySelector('.info_pack_money .currency').textContent = data.summa.currency;
  return info;
}
```

```html
<button id="add">add</button>
<div class="info"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно выделить общие действия по созданию элементов в функцию и вызывать ее с нужными параметрами.

В данной функции можно собрать установку классов, добавление дочерних узлов, добавление атрибутов и т.д.

Простой вариант функции может выглядеть так:

```
function element(elementName, options, ...childs) {
  const element = (options.attrs || []).reduce(
    (element, attr) => element.setAttribute(attr.name, attr.value) || element, // добавляем элементу атрибуты
    document.createElement(elementName) // создаем элемент
  );
  element.className = (options.classes || []).join(' '); // добавляем классы
  element.textContent = options.textContent; // устанавливаем textContent
  return childs.reduce((element, child) => element.appendChild(child) && element, element); // добавляем дочерние узлы
}
```

Далее можно вокруг этой функции построить более специализированные, например функция для `div`

```
function div(options, ...childs) {
  return element('div', options, ...childs);
}
```

или span

```
function span(options, ...childs) {
  return element('span', options, ...childs);
}
```

---

Далее все сводится к вызову функций, например:

```js
function element(elementName, options, ...childs) {
  const element = (options.attrs || []).reduce((element, attr) => element.setAttribute(attr.name, attr.value) || element, document.createElement(elementName));
  element.className = (options.classes || []).join(' ');
  element.textContent = options.textContent;
  return childs.reduce((element, child) => element.appendChild(child) && element, element);
}

function div(options, ...childs) {
  return element('div', options, ...childs);
}

function img(options) {
  var img = element('img', options);
  img.style.width = options.width;
  img.style.height = options.height;
  img.src = options.src;
  return img;
}

function span(options, ...childs) {
  return element('span', options, ...childs);
}
var doc = {
  id: 'id',
  data() {
    return {
      src: 'https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cryptocoins/227/XRP-alt-512.png',
      cryptoname: 'ripple',
      income: '1008.00'
    }
  }
}
orders.appendChild(
  div({attrs: [{name: 'data-id',value: doc.id}]},
    div({classes: ['info_pack']},
      div({classes: ['info_pack_row']},
        div({classes: ['info_pack_row_img']},
          img({width: '30px',height: '30px',src: doc.data().src})
        ),
        div({classes: ['info_pack_text'],textContent: doc.data().cryptoname})
      ),
      div({classes: ['info_pack_money'],textContent: doc.data().income},
        span({textContent: '$'})))));
```

```html
<div id="orders"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

В своем комментарии к вопросу, я упоминал про js-шаблонизатор. Хочу показать решение задачи автора, с применением [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/).

Определяем шаблон для представления данных, сами данные и вызываем шаблонизатор, который генерирует чанк html-разметки. Полученный чанк, вставляем в DOM-дерево документа.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>foobar - Hadlebars</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="output">Здесь скоро появятся данные ;)</div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.1.0/handlebars.js"></script>

  <script id="foobar-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="info_pack" data-id="{{ id }}">
      <div class="info_pack_row">
        <div class="info_pack_row_img">
          <img src="{{ data.src }}" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;">
        </div>
        <div class="info_pack_text">{{ data.cryptoname }}</div>
      </div>
      <div class="info_pack_money">{{ data.income }}<span>$</span></div>
    </div>
  </script>

  <script>
    window.onload = function(e) {
      var source   = document.getElementById("foobar-template").innerHTML;
      var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
      var data  = {
        id: 'id123',
        data: {
          src: "images/XRP.png",
          cryptoname: "ripple",
          income: 1008.00
        }
      };

      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = template(data);
    };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```